# Matlab - refresh 3D volume (slice) with GUI

Tags: matlab, user-interface, multidimensional-array, matlab-figure, slice

I would like to refresh my figure (3D, obtained with the matlab slice command) using a slider (GUI) to update the slice position.

Here is my code to create the figure (it works):

```
% Create figure

Fig_3dview = figure;
Fig_3dview.Name= 'Microstructure viewer';

% hold on;
% The data to be displayed are within "Volume", a n*m*k matrix
Domain_size = size(Volume)

% Initial position of the slices
% Basically, the 6 faces of the volume
xslice = [1,Domain_size(1)]; 
yslice = [1,Domain_size(2)];
zslice = [1,Domain_size(3)]; 

% Display all the slices
imslice = slice(Volume,xslice,yslice,zslice,'parent',Fig_3dview);

% Remove voxel edge
set(imslice,'edgecolor','none')

% Current axis label
ax_3d_slice = gca;

% Set axis equal and tight
axis equal tight

hold off;
```

The code for the GUI, to control the slice position (it doesn't work):

```
% Create GUI figure
Fig_3dview_GUI = figure;
Fig_3dview_GUI.Name= 'Microstructure viewer 3D GUI';

% Create slider    
    h_slice1 = uicontrol('Style','slider','BackgroundColor','w',...
        'Unit','pixels','Position',[10,200,250,50],'Parent',Fig_3dview_GUI,...
        'Callback',{@slider_slice1_Callback});

% Define function associated with h_slice1 
    function slider_slice1_Callback(source,eventdata)
        % Determine the selected data set.
        pos_normalized = source.Value;
        position_slice_1= round(pos_normalized*Domain_size(1)); % Get closest integer value
        position_slice_1=max(1,position_slice_1); % 0 must be avoided

% Update figure
```

And here I don't know how to update the figure Fig_3dview with the new position for the slice normal to the first direction.
I would like the new figure looks like:

```
xslice = [position_slice_1,Domain_size(1)];
imslice = slice(Volume,xslice,yslice,zslice,'parent',Fig_3dview);
```

I do not want to close the figure and regenerate it, I want to refresh it, so that I get a smooth visualization.

```
        % Update figure
    end
```

Thanks for any advice.
François